# opening project in web browser in expo, error in node-fetch

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

When I run `expo start` and write down **w** it displays this error message.
[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvE10.png)

and if I try to open in the web it displays an error saying to see the logs, but no logs appear.
[Error in web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LV4IY.png)

I want to know if there is any solution, because I've already searched and tried many things but none of them seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fully sure what the issue is. However, I recommend this cause of action:

1. Ensure npm is up to date. (npm -v)
2. Ensure nodejs is up to date. (Check version node -v)
3. Inside your expo project directory install node modules (npm install)

   1. Maybe also try expo install
4. expo start

If that doesn't work, then start a new expo project ensure it works and then start moving code from your old project into the new one. Move small chunks of code at a time until you find what caused the error.

Comment: I solved it by doing `npm install -g expo-cli` . Maybe something wrong with npm installation?